# grunt-bowercopy produces warning - No files copied

Tags: npm, gruntjs, bower

I've set Grunt to compile compass with watch task and now I'd like to copy useful files from *bower_components/...* - e.g. bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js, because bower produces a lot of unnecessary files, which I want to get rid of, when uploading to server.

CMD produces warning and stops process;

```
    Reading C:\Users\sjiamnocna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PM_new\node_modules\grunt-bowercopy\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\sjiamnocna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PM_new\node_modules\grunt-bowercopy\package.json...OK
Reading bower.json...OK
Parsing bower.json...OK
Loading "bowercopy.js" tasks...OK
+ bowercopy
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default, dog

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "bowercopy" task

Running "bowercopy:copythat" (bowercopy) task
Verifying property bowercopy.copythat exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: srcPrefix="bower_components", destPrefix="files", ignore=[], report, runBower=false, clean=false, copyOptions={}
Using srcPrefix: bower_components
Using destPrefix: files
Warning: Nothing was copied for the "copythat" target Use --force to continue.
```

My gruntfile:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            scss: {
                files: ['files/style/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            }
        },
        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'files/style/sass',
                    cssDir: 'files/style',
                    environment: 'development'
                }
            }
        },
        bowercopy: {
            copythat: {
                options: {
                    runBower: false,
                    srcPrefix: 'bower_components',
                    destPrefix: 'files'
                },
                script: {
                    'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js': 'script/lib/jquery.min.js',
                    'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js': 'script/lib/jquery-ui.min.js',
                    'masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js': 'script/lib/masonry.pkgd.min.js',
                    'sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js': 'script/lib/sweetalert.min.js'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['bowercopy']);
    grunt.registerTask('dog', ['watch']);

};
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Or, is there any other way to do it with grunt (automatically :) )?

Comment: Under `copythat`, rename the `script` key to `files`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cartant for comment, it was one of the mistakes I've made - using whatever instead of "files"

I've changed position of resource and target

Wrong:

```
'source':'target'
```

improved:

```
'target':'source'
```

Works!